# Apache HTTP Server Config Variable is not defined ERROR ***How to solve?***

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2

```
Tue May 03 16:22:16.481248 2022] [core:warn] [pid 123243] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
```

apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2022-03-25T00:35:40
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:121
Server loaded:  APR 1.7.0, APR-UTIL 1.6.1
Compiled using: APR 1.7.0, APR-UTIL 1.6.1
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     
Server compiled with....
-D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
-D APR_HAS_MMAP
-D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
-D APR_USE_PROC_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
-D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
-D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
-D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
-D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
-D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
-D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
-D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
-D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
-D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
-D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
-D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

Answer (score 0):

This message is displayed because you directly executed the apache2 binary. In Ubuntu/Debian the apache config relies on the envvar file which is only activated.

If you start apache with the init script or apachectl.

Your original problem is that you have no a proper hostname (fqdn) for your machine.

If you can't change it, change the ServerName variable in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf to localhost or your prefered FQDN.

Comment: Being that I'm an inexperienced newbie. Can you share basic instructions? I don't yet know how to solve this issue.